# undefined is not a function when importing a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have to files one main file and one file called rest.js

In my main file I call getToken after pressing a button, which calles getData from rest.js - but all I get is _rest2.default.getData is not a Function

```
import rest from './rest.js';

class Login extends Component {
[...]
  let response = rest.getData(this.state.token,
    'https://example.com/endpoint/').done();
[...]
```

rest.js

```
 /*jshint esversion: 6 */
function getData(token, url) {
  var responseJson = fetch(url,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        Host: 'example.com',
      },
    }
  ).then(function (response) {
     return response.json();});

  return responseJson;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rest` module should `export` `getData` function to make it available for importing:

```
 /*jshint esversion: 6 */
export function getData(token, url) {
  // function code
}
```

Also import syntax you are using is meant for importing default export of the module. To import complete module you should use `import * as rest from './rest.js'`

Answer (score 1):

There might be an issue with the 'import' statement. If you put all your code in one file, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `export` the function in your rest.js

```
export function getData(token, url) {
   ...
}
```